# What are (U) Events in the Dymola Simulation log

Tags: events, modelica, dymola

When a Dymola model is run the following table is generated in the Simulation log:
Integration terminated successfully at T = 4 
   CPU-time for integration      : 0.002 seconds 
   CPU-time for one GRID interval: 0.2 milli-seconds 
 
   Number of result points       : 11 
   Number of GRID   points       : 11 
   Number of (successful) steps  : 227 
   Number of F-evaluations       : 785 
   Number of H-evaluations       : 261 
   Number of Jacobian-evaluations: 68 
   Number of (model) time events : 4 
   Number of (U) time events     : 0 
   Number of state    events     : 2 
   Number of step     events     : 0 
   Minimum integration stepsize  : 3.24e-005 
   Maximum integration stepsize  : 0.317 
   Maximum integration order     : 5

What is the meaning of "Number of (U) time events"?

Comment: You might want to read: http://www.claytex.com/blog/understanding-the-simulation-log-basics/

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out:
(U) time events occur when using dsu.txt and there are events in dsu.txt.